# How to create a Symfony2 drop down form element from mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I'm new to mongodb and asking my self how to implement the following:

I would like to have a set of values, for example names of persons, in a drop down form element. 
These names are loaded from a collection. If one ore more names are selected from the drop down
these names should be saved in another collection in an array. I don't want to have relations
between collection persons and the other collection.

In my opinion this is similar to the star schema in the SQL world - but without relations between the tables.

But until now I din't figure out how to solve this with Symfony2 and Mongodb ...

Would be happy if someone could help !